# Two nested Groovy closures -- looking for cleaner syntax

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm unfamiliar with Groovy syntax, but spent a bit of time researching this. I'm working with a Jenkinsfile, and I have a section that looks like this:

```
configFileProvider([/* ... */]) {
  withCredentials([/* ... */]) {
    sh 'my command'
  }
}
```

Does Groovy syntax enable a shorter expression of this same logic? I'm not a fan of the indentation here.

Comment: question is not to groovy but to plugin that requires [exactly this syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/). however you cal put all in one line `configFileProvider([/* ... */]) { withCredentials([/* ... */]) { sh 'my command' }}` or create own [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) with simpler syntax as you like

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any closure to a variable and pass it.  So you could refactor to:

```
def shCommand = { withCredentials([...]) {
  sh 'my command'
}}
configFileProvider([...], shCommand)
```

or

```
def shCommand = {
  sh 'my command'
}
configFileProvider([...]) {
  withCredentials([...], shCommand)
}
```